# Fine Uploader: how can I append input hidden fields to the autoupload?

Tags: jquery, forms, fine-uploader

I had to move from dropzone.js to Fine Uploader because of the missing client resize image feature on the first one.
So I'm now having some issues trying to get the same results as I got with dropzone.

I need to append some hidden input fields to the image to be uploaded which it was easy to do on dropzone.
I've tried the Form option as described on Docs, but it sends all the form elements to the form action, but I only need to send just few data to a different page to perform Ajax requests on server side (hope it does make sense)

Input fields I need to append are:

the script I'm using:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fine-uploader').fineUploader({
            template: 'qq-template',
            form: {
                element: 'modulomezzi',
                autoUpload: true
            },
            request: {
                endpoint: 'ajax_page.asp',
                inputName: 'foto_gallery1'
            },
            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    waitingPath: '/fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                    notAvailablePath: '/fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
                }
            },
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
            }
        });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: the `form` option will submit all your form inputs to the endpoint. If you want to control which parameters to send to your API, don't use `form`, use `request.params`.

Comment: Thanks @tropicalfish! Can you turn this comment into an answer with an example for the question asker? Also be sure to mention the setParams API method too.

Comment: Thanks @tropicalfish , that was an option I tried but didn't work, I probably did something wrong, an example would be really appreciate to me too!

Comment: @RayNicholus, answer added below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `request.params` option like below:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: document.getElementById("uploader"),
        template: 'qq-template',
        request: {
            endpoint: '/api/saveimage',
            params: {'param1': 'someValue', 'param2': document.getElementById('textInputId').value},
        },
        thumbnails: {
            placeholders: {
                waitingPath: '/img/fine-uploader/waiting-generic.png',
                notAvailablePath: '/img/fine-uploader/not_available-generic.png'
            }
        },
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
            itemLimit: 3
        },
    });
```

You can also use the `setParams` API to set your parameters with js anytime you see fit:

```
var params = {'param1': 'somevalue1', 'param2': 'somevalue2'};
uploader.setParams(params);
```

See doc: [setParams](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setParams)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is the solution, thanks to @tropicalfish for pointing me to the right direction.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fine-uploader').fineUploader({
            template: 'qq-template',
            request: {
                endpoint: '<% =pagina_ajax %>',
                inputName: '<% =paramName %>',
                params: {
                    id: '<% =idvalue %>'
                }
            },
            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    waitingPath: '/fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                    notAvailablePath: '/fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
                }
            },
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
            }
        });
});
```